# Subsonic 3 templates in VS 2010 Beta 2

Tags: subsonic, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to setup Subsonic ActiveRecord in a web application in Visual Studio 2010 beta 2. In any scenario I get the same error:

Warning 1   The path 'D:\Work\Project\tt\SQLServer.ttinclude' must be either local to this computer or part of your trusted zone.

Everything works just fine on the same machine with VS 2008.

Does anyone else have this problem? Is it supposed to work with VS 2010 and .net 4.0 or I should stick with vs 2008 for the time beeing?

Comment: Is your D: drive a network share?

Comment: Did you ever get a handle on this Alex?

Comment: No, I have tried your solution, but it didn't work. I gave up for now.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured out *one* solution. I'm sure there could be others out there.  I got around this issue by opening VS.NET 2010 and selecting 'Tools | Extenstion Manager' and clicking on the "Online Gallery" option. I selected the Tangible T4 Template Editor and installed the plugin/extension.  If you don't see the extension then try sorting by highest rated or perform a search for it.

I closed VS and re-opened the tt file after closing it and voila!  No more compile errors ;)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same error "must be either local to this computer or part of your trusted zone", I did get it to work without adding anything to the Trusted Zone, the only thing I did was remove the "language" setting in the SQLServer.ttinclude file, and then edit the files a little (add a space, remove it, save etc.) not sure if this was enough to convince it to build properly the next time I did "Run Custom Tool" on each of the T4 files, but it worked, phew!

Comment: I can't find any language setting in SQLServer.ttinclude, there is one only in settings.ttinclude

Comment: Mmm- after trying some more updates, I think that there just seems to be a lag with VS2010, and that any changes I made would eventually start working after just editing something trivial (e.g. whitespace) in the file and that once VS had rebuilt the .cs file in the background everything would be fine.

Comment: Did this, but to no avail.  Will hack at it some more.

Answer (score 1):

I recently hit this on a new Windows 7 (64 bit) install.  Once you download the archive, right click on the file and select Unblock before you extract it and all is well.  Note that this applies to the VS 2010 release as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add the network share to Trusted sites. First uncheck the *Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone* checkbox.